# Failed to lookup view "board/index" in views directory "/sites/ZhongShuo/views"

Tags: sails.js

I created a sails.js web application in my mac book air. I tested it and made sure it run smoothly. But after I deployed the application to the linux server, I got 500 internal server error when I tried to access a specific url. The error info is shown below:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Error: Failed to lookup view "board/index" in views directory "/sites/ZhongShuo/views"
    at Function.app.render (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:512:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:827:7)
    at Object.module.exports.index (/sites/ZhongShuo/api/controllers/BoardController.js:10:7)
    at bound (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at param (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at nextRoute (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
    at callbacks (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
    at /sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:187:7
    at alwaysAllow (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:207:11)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:179:5)
    at callbacks (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/sites/ZhongShuo/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11) { [Error: Failed to lookup view "board/index" in views directory "/sites/ZhongShuo/views"]
  view: 
   { name: 'board/index',
     root: '/sites/ZhongShuo/views',
     defaultEngine: 'ejs',
     ext: '.ejs',
     engine: [Function],
     path: undefined } }
```

The Board.ejs file does exist in the /sites/ZhongShuo/views/Board/ directory. I just can't figure out why this error would occur.

Comment: What's calling your view a controller/action or a route?  What does the code look like that's calling this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly a case-sensitivity issue.  Your MacBook is case-insensitive, so it sees `board.ejs` and `Board.ejs` as the same file, but the flavor of Linux you deployed to is case-sensitive and sees them as different.  Either change your code to `res.view('Board')` or (my advice) change the filename to be all lowercase.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly! Thanks so much for solving my problem!